# how to comment both html and php blocks in sublime text3?

Tags: php, html, sublimetext3

I have to comment a block of PHP and HTML code in Sublime Text3. Is there a shortcut or plugin available that I can use to comment this code block? Please check with the below code

```
<div class="product-info">
    <div class="form-group product-fields">
    <label for="fields"><?php echo lang('designer_right_choose_product_color'); ?></label>
    <div class="list-colors" id="product-list-colors">

        <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($product->design->color_hex); $i++) { ?>
        <span class="bg-colors dg-tooltip <?php if ($i==0) echo 'active'; ?>" onclick="design.products.changeColor(this, <?php echo $i; ?>)" data-color="<?php echo $product->design->color_hex[$i]; ?>" data-placement="top" data-original-title="<?php echo $product->design->color_title[$i]; ?>">

            <?php 
                $colors_hex = explode(';', $product->design->color_hex[$i]);
                $span_with = (23/count($colors_hex));
            ?>
            <?php for($jc=0; $jc<count($colors_hex); $jc++) { ?>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="width:<?php echo $span_with; ?>px; background-color:#<?php echo $colors_hex[$jc]; ?>"></a>
            <?php } ?>
        </span>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: select all, then ctrl+/

Comment: @cokile not working

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Try `command + /` instead.

Comment: it's based on OS which button you'll push - but as @CameronHurd said cmd + / on OS X and as Cokile said, CTRL + / for Win (and Linux I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Best way (for me) is using php comment for both html and php:

```
<?php /* comment start
<div>
<label ...
<?php ... some php code
?>
...
comment end */ ?>
```